# How to tell find command to escape space characters in file names?

Tags: bash, find

I have a single line find command, which recursively checks and prints out the size, owner and name of a specific file type which are created in a specific time frame. But in the result, the filename column is given until the first space character in the directory or file name.
Any idea to fix this problem right in this single command without writing any loop in the bash? Thanks!

here is the command:

```
find /path/to/dist -type f -iname "*.png" -newermt 2015-01-01 ! -newermt 2016-12-31 -ls | sort -k5 | sort -k5 | awk '{print $5"\t"$7"\t"$11}'
```

Comment: Shell-escaping the names won't help you. `sort` has no idea about escaping.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your `awk` command to this :

```
awk '{$1=$2=$3=$4=$6=$8=$9=$10="" ; print$11}'
```

So that the whole command becomes this :

```
find /path/to/dist -type f -iname "*.png" -newermt 2015-01-01 ! -newermt 2016-12-31 -ls | sort -k5 | awk '{$1=$2=$3=$4=$6=$8=$9=$10="" ; print$0}'
```

This leaves some extra spaces at the beginning of the line, hopefully it works for your purpose.

I have removed the second instance of `sort`, as it sorts on the same key as the first, which does not seem likely to do anything.

Answer (score 1):

Well thanks to Arno's input, the following line does the job. I used exec (`-exec ls -lh {} \;`) to make the size human readable:

```
find /Path/To/Dest/ -type f -iname "*.pdf" -newermt 2015-01-01 ! -newermt 2016-12-31 -exec ls -lh {} \; |sed 's/\\ /!!!/g' | sort -k5 | awk '{gsub("!!!"," ",$11);print $3"\t"$5"\t"$9}'
```

Answer (score 0):

The `-print0` action of `find` is probably the starting point. From find's manual page:

```
   -print0
          True;  print  the  full file name on the standard output,
          followed by a null  character  (instead  of  the  newline
          character that -print uses).  This allows file names that
          contain newlines or other types of white space to be cor‐
          rectly interpreted by programs that process the find out‐
          put.  This option corresponds to the -0 option of xargs.
```

But `find` has the nice `printf` action that is even better:

```
find /path/to/dist -type f -iname "*.png" -newermt 2015-01-01 ! -newermt 2016-12-31 -printf "%u\t%s\t%p\n" | sort
```

probably does the job.

Comment: the problem with -print0 is that he needs a `ls` option to have information on owner and size.

Comment: You're right. I suggested to feed the output to `xargs` with a command that does the job. But it's probably more complex than needed. I edited my answer to suggest a better way.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following solution. You hide the space in filename. I did it with a sed, I used a strange chain "!!!" to replace "\ ". Then I replace it in awk command. Here is the command I used for my tests:

```
find . -type f -iname "*.pdf" -newermt 2015-01-01  -ls |sed 's/\\ /!!!/g' | sort -k5 | awk '{gsub("!!!"," ",$11);print $5"\t"$7"\t"$11}'
```

Comment: Thanks Arno! This worked great!
For human readable size I changed it a bit using exec, also the columns should have been changed too:
find /path/to/Dist -type f -iname "*.pdf" -newermt 2015-01-01 ! -newermt 2016-12-31 -exec ls -lh {} \; |sed 's/\\ /!!!/g' | sort -k5 | awk '{gsub("!!!"," ",$11);print $3"\t"$5"\t"$9}'